# What's the meaning difference between "the meat of a deer" and "the meat from a deer"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, word-difference

Macmillan dictionary
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/venison

> the meat **from** a deer

Longman dictionary
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/venison

> the meat **of** a deer

I'd like to inquire about what the meaning difference between them is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a definition of "venison", they mean the same thing.

"The meat **from** a deer" implies that the meat used to be part of a living deer, but no longer is.

Whereas "The meat **of** a deer can mean either the flesh that currently is part of a living deer, or flesh that used to be part of a living deer.

Comment: I’m immensely grateful to you for your help.